# CSS/HTML How to Preserve formation of text in html

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Is there any way to preserve the text spaces in HTML? As per below i get some feeds from third party service but feeds out put just have a text not HTML formatted tag so is there any way to show the texts properly on web page.

[image]

As you can see in the picture text don't have any proper paragraph format but return text has it so is there any way to reflect same in the html page? I tried below properties of css but it doesn't works.

```
white-space: pre;
word-wrap: break-word;
```

In case of **"white-space: pre;"** text goes end less.
[image]

Comment: `white-space: pre` will do that.

Comment: I'd write a script to convert `/n` newlines into a `</p><p>` or double `<br>`

Comment: Seems like a  litle bit of CSS might go a long way here.

Comment: Can you try `white-space: pre-wrap`?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:-

```
white-space:pre;
width:1em;
overflow-wrap: break-word;
```

word-wrap property is deprecated, try using overflow-wrap

Answer (score 0):

Setting `pre-wrap` for whitespace.

> **This value prevents user agents from collapsing sequences of white space**. Lines are broken at newlines in the source, at occurrences of "\A" in generated content, and as necessary to fill line boxes.

```
white-space: pre-wrap
```

#### Reference

https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/white-space

Answer (score 0):

You can just write your article in different paragraph tags. It will create spaces between different lines.

Example:

```
   <p>this is paragraph 1</p>
  <p>this is paragraph 2</p>
  <p>this is paragraph 3</p>
```